# ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command give

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
intents.message_content = True #v2

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user.name}')

@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def give(ctx: commands.Context, user_id: int):
    user = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
    if user:
        role_ids = [1162989885439885323, 1162991880687063172, 1160602324633387178, 1161231761083211856, 1161231909544800286]  # 역할 아이디를 여기에 입력합니다.

        for role_id in role_ids:
            role = ctx.guild.get_role(role_id)
            if role:
                await user.add_roles(role)

        await ctx.send(f'{user.display_name}님에게 역할을 지급했습니다.')
        print('정상작동완료')
    else:
        await ctx.send('유저를 찾을 수 없습니다.')

bot.run('no')
```

!give is a bot that gives you a role when you enter your user ID, but it doesn't work and only shows ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command give. How do I resolve this?

I don't no how to do..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the ['How do I ask a good question?' guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and make sure to include the full traceback (the error message) in your original post so we can help you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.